# Chrome desktop does not save password after old password removed in settings

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, passwords, password-management

Previously I had removed saved password of a website in the chrome settings. Now, each time that I login to that site, chrome does not offer to save the password, so I have to repeat entering the credentials again and again, which is a pain in the neck.

How can I fix it?